# Add hyphens to mobile number

Tags: text-manipulation, number, href

I want to add my mobile number in a pdf line being generated using LaTeX

how I want it to render: `(+91) 7887-61x-xxx`

usage: `\mobile{91}{788761xxxx}`

```
% Usage: \mobile{<countrycode><mobile number>}
\newcommand*{\mobile}[2]{\def\@countrycode{#1}\def\@mobileno{#2}}
\newcommand*{\countrycode}[1]{\def\@countrycode{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mobileno}[1]{\def\@mobileno{#1}}
```

The purpose to separate countrycode is bcz I wanto use WhatsApp API using following code:

`href{https://wa.me/\@countrycode\@mobileno}{(+\@countrycode) \@mobileno}`

How do I add spaces/hyphens in above case using LaTeX?

I want the url to be `https://wa.me/91788761xxxx` but text to be `(+91)7887-61x-xxx`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Do you have any need to represent mobile numbers from other areas?  For example, fhe pattern is different in North America: (+1)(123) 456-7890

Comment: @barbarabeeton, no I just wanted to customize for my local format as I'm using it for resume/cv only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also change the hyphenation format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mobile}{O{433}mm}
 {
  \href{https://wa.me/#2#3}{\printmobile[#1]{#2}{#3}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printmobile}{O{433}mm}
 {
  \saste_mobile:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__saste_mobile_index_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \saste_mobile:nnn
 {
  (+#2)\nobreakspace\__saste_mobile:nn { #1 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__saste_mobile:nn
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__saste_mobile_index_int { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { 1 } }
  \tl_range:nnn { #2 } { 1 } { \l__saste_mobile_index_int } % first group
  \int_step_inline:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } - 1 }
   {
    -
    \tl_range:nnn { #2 }
     { \l__saste_mobile_index_int + 1 } % start point
     { \l__saste_mobile_index_int + \tl_item:nn { #1 } { ##1+1 } } % end point
    \int_set:Nn \l__saste_mobile_index_int
     { \l__saste_mobile_index_int + \tl_item:nn { #1 } { ##1+1 } } % for next cycle
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mobile{91}{1234567890} \mobile[342]{91}{123456789}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument is a sequence of digits that specifies how many digits from the following number go in each of the hyphen-separated groups. Thus different national conventions can be accommodated. The default is `433`.

In the picture the URL corresponding to the first number is shown through hovering on it.

[image]

Based on the above code, we can also make much more customizations.

With `\setmobile`, which can go anywhere including the document preamble, you can set the options to be used from that point on (but it obeys the standard grouping rules).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mobile}{O{}mm}
 {
  \href{https://wa.me/#2#3}{\printmobile[#1]{#2}{#3}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printmobile}{O{}mm}
 {
  \saste_mobile:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setmobile}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { saste/mobile } { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__saste_mobile_index_int

\keys_define:nn { saste/mobile }
 {
  parens   .bool_set:N         = \l__saste_mobile_parens_bool,
  parens   .default:n          = true,
  parens   .initial:n          = true,
  noparens .bool_set_inverse:N = \l__saste_mobile_parens_bool,
  noparens .default:n          = true,
  presep   .tl_set:N           = \l__saste_mobile_presep_tl,
  presep   .initial:n          = \nobreakspace,
  sep      .tl_set:N           = \l__saste_mobile_sep_tl,
  sep      .initial:n          = -,
  format   .tl_set:N           = \l__saste_mobile_format_tl,
  format   .initial:n          = 433,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \saste_mobile:nnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { saste/mobile } { #1 }
  \bool_if:NT \l__saste_mobile_parens_bool { ( }
  +#2
  \bool_if:NT \l__saste_mobile_parens_bool { ) }
  \l__saste_mobile_presep_tl
  \__saste_mobile:n { #3 }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__saste_mobile:n
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__saste_mobile_index_int { \tl_item:Nn \l__saste_mobile_format_tl { 1 } }
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { \l__saste_mobile_index_int } % first group
  \int_step_inline:nn { \tl_count:N \l__saste_mobile_format_tl - 1 }
   {
    \l__saste_mobile_sep_tl
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 }
     { \l__saste_mobile_index_int + 1 } % start point
     { \l__saste_mobile_index_int + \tl_item:Nn \l__saste_mobile_format_tl { ##1+1 } } % end point
    \int_set:Nn \l__saste_mobile_index_int
     { \l__saste_mobile_index_int + \tl_item:Nn \l__saste_mobile_format_tl { ##1+1 } } % for next cycle
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mobile{91}{1234567890}

\bigskip\bigskip

\mobile[format=342]{91}{123456789}

\mobile[noparens,presep=\,,sep=\,,format=333]{91}{123456789}

\setmobile{noparens,presep=\,,sep=\,,format=433}

\mobile{91}{1234567890}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a really great solution, I'm a novice when it comes to writing using LaTeX, the document I'm trying to edit is 'Awesome Resume' - https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm can u guide me a little to implement this change while keeping the well organized structured code has?

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste Just place this code, from the first `\NewDocumentCommand` up to `\ExplSyntaxOff` inclusive in the CONFIGURATIONS part.

Answer (score 3):

If the digits are fixed you may do something like this

```
\newcommand*\countrycode{\gdef\@countrycode}
\newcommand*\mobileno{\gdef\@mobileno}

\newcommand*\mobile[2]{\countrycode{#1}\expandafter\mobileno\expandafter{\mobileA#2}}
\def\mobileA#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{#1#2#3#4-#5#6#7-}
```

Then after running `\mobile{91}{788761xxxx}` you would get `7887-61x-xxx` in `\@mobileno`, but it is not clear if this what you want.

Comment: I want the url to be `https://wa.me/91788761xxxx` but text to be 7887-61x-xxx

Comment: then just use `\mobileA` where you want the hyphens, for example with your original code `\expandafter\mobileA \@mobile`

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a position to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document, the following solution may be of interest to you. It defines a "wrapper macro" called `\mobile`, which passes its arguments to a Lua function called `mobile` (how unoriginal...). The Lua function, in turn, makes use of Lua's `string.sub` ("subset (of a string)") built-in function to get the job done.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
```

```lua
  function mobile ( a , b )
    tex.sprint ( "(+"..a..") "..b:sub(1,4).."-"..b:sub(5,7).."-"..b:sub(8) )
  end
```

```tex
}
% define a LaTeX wrapper macro:
\newcommand\mobile[2]{\directlua{mobile ( "#1" , "#2" )}}

\begin{document}
output of \verb+\mobile{91}{788761xxxx}+:
\mobile{91}{788761xxxx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I could add that the LaTeX macro `\mobile` is expandable (in the TeX-specific sense of the word) and hence can be used in the arguments of other TeX and LaTeX macros,